# Disable Hibernate provider_disables_autocommit in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to set common hibernate property:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit" value="true"/>
```

in my SpringBoot project, but i find only property in application.properties like this:

```
spring.datasource.auto-commit=false
```

i'am not sure, if it the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html):

> `spring.jpa.properties.*` - Additional native properties to set on the JPA provider.